# Unable to get Output of Custom Function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

My Data Table is as below

| Serial No | Academic | Year | Current year |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | 0.0 | 0 | 2022 |
| 1 | 0.0 | 0 | 2022 |
| 2 | 0.0 | 0 | 2022 |
| 3 | 0.0 | 0 | 2022 |
| 4 | 0.0 | 0 | 2022 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |
| 5298 | 0.0 | 0 | 2019 |
| 5299 | 0.0 | 0 | 2019 |
| 5300 | 0.0 | 0 | 2019 |
| 5301 | 3.0 | 0 | 2019 |
| 5302 | 3.0 | 0 | 2019 |

my custom code

```
def convert(Academic, current, year):
    if Academic == 0.0 | current == 0:
        year += 4
    elif Academic == 1.0 | current == 1:
        year += 3
    elif Academic == 2.0 | current == 2:
        year += 2
    elif Academic == 3.0 | current == 3:
        year += 1
    else:
        year
    return year
```

apply the function to get a new pandas column

```
df['Passing'] = df.apply(convert(df["Academic"], df["current"], df["year"]), axis=1)
```

It always gives me error `The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

I have tried changing the pipe operator to OR and vice versa, but it still produces the same error.

Comment: data has 3(?) columns "Academic", "Year",   "Current year" , but I do see 4 values `1`,   `0.0`,  `0`,   `2022`.  Can you use [edit] and improve the layout of that data ?

Comment: @Luuk First line row is just Serial no.... You can avoid it.. Sorry for that

Comment: I edited to make the table look better.

Comment: What's the question? Like, what do you need help with exactly? Do you understand what the error is saying? Please read [ask] and [edit] to clarify. To me the error is clear as day, but I guess I have the benefit of experience: you're passing in three Series instead of three values. I think you meant `lambda row: convert(row["Academic"], row["current"], row["year"])`. That said, there are [better ways to do the same thing](/a/19913845/4518341), and changing the pipe to `or` was a good idea.

Comment: Secondly, please make a [reproducible pandas example](/q/20109391/4518341), meaning don't include any irrelevant details (serial column), show your expected output, and make sure the column names match (`Year` != `year`, `Current year` != `current`, but also `Current year == 0` wouldn't make sense).

Comment: "It always gives me error" - this is because your code means "**Call `convert` now**, passing it these **entire columns**, and then use **the result** for the `apply` call". That first step fails because the function is designed to handle single cell values, not entire columns. You cannot use `if` in whole-column logic **for the same reason** that you cannot use `or` (I see that you already tried to work around `or` by using `|` instead). But if you fix `convert` to use whole-column logic, **then you do not need or want `apply` any more**.

Comment: Yes thank you.. I  didnt know that you cannot pass table to apply. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue here is that you're not using `.apply` quite correctly. Your first argument should be a function, but what you gave it was a function *call* - the output of a single use of a function. And that single use is giving an error because you're feeding it entire columns, but it's expecting single values. Because the value you passed for `Academic` is a series, `Academic == 0.0` gives a series of true and false values, and the error indicates that `if` doesn't know what to do with that.

When `axis=1`, `.apply` expects the first argument to be a function with a single input, and `.apply` will run that function with a single row (as a pandas series), and repeat this for every row. We can build this out of your existing function with lambda:

```
df['Passing'] = df.apply(lambda row: convert(row['Academic'], row['current'], row['year']), axis=1)
```

I used the column names you have in your `.apply`, but they don't quite match what your table shows, so double check that you're using the right column labels in the intended order.

You could also avoid lambda by reworking your `convert` function to take the row as a single input (`def convert(row): ...`) then applying it directly like:

```
df['Passing'] = df.apply(convert, axis=1)
```

Notice that with that approach we're passing the actual `convert` function with no `()`, rather than a function call `convert()`. It's not really important to avoid lambda like this, it's just a little more readable.